# Running a command from the loop

Tags: windbg, sos, sosex

I would like to run !refs command against each address from following command

```
!dumpgen 2 -type System.DateTime[]
```

How this could be done.I know a loop can be created as follows

```
.foreach (myvar {!dumpgen 2 -type System.DateTime[]})
```

But how can I access object address that could be used in loop with !refs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!dumpgen` does not have a `-short` argument like `!dumpheap` has and I'd really like to see a simpler answer than this one.

### Approach 1: dump a generation manually

1. Get the addresses of the heap

   ```
   0:003> !eeheap -gc
   Number of GC Heaps: 1
   generation 0 starts at 0x026f1018
   generation 1 starts at 0x026f100c
   generation 2 starts at 0x026f1000
   ```
2. Use the addresses to limit the output to the generation you want:

   ```
   !dumpheap -type X <start> <end>
   ```
3. Use the `-short` parameter on `!dumpheap`, which outputs the address only. This address of an object can then be processed by other commands.

Also note: using `-type` may result in other types as well. Better use the method table with `-mt` since only that guarantees the uniqueness of types. Use `!name2ee` if you don't get that from elsewhere.

A complete session could look like this:

```
0:003> !dumpheap -stat
total 345 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
53ab421c        1           12 System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallback
[...]
53ab0d48      135         6640 System.String
53a84518       26         9452 System.Object[]
Total 345 objects

0:003> !eeheap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x026f1018
generation 1 starts at 0x026f100c
generation 2 starts at 0x026f1000
[...]

0:003> !name2ee *!System.String
Module: 53841000 (mscorlib.dll)
Token: 0x02000024
MethodTable: 53ab0d48
[...]

0:003> !dumpheap -short -mt 53ab0d48 0x026f1000 0x026f100c
```

(Ok, all my strings seem to be in generation 0, damn :-)

```
0:003> .foreach (addr {!dumpheap -short -mt 53ab0d48 0x026f1018}) {!refs ${addr}}
```

Disadvantage: you need to do that for all GC heaps separately. There could be several of them.

### Approach 2: decide for the generation on each single object

Another ugly solution is to

1. Dump all object addresses (`!dumpheap -short` and `-type` or `-mt`)
2. Query the generation of each object via `!gcgen`
3. Depending on the generation, execute a command

Here's how to do it (formatted for readability, put it all into one line):

```
.foreach (addr {!dumpheap -short -mt 53ab0d48}) {
    .foreach /pS 1 (gen {!gcgen ${addr}}) { 
        .if ($scmp("${gen}","2")==0) {
            !refs ${addr}
        }
    }
}
```

where `53ab0d48` is the method table of the type you're looking for and `"2"` is the generation you want. `/pS 1` skips the word "Gen" in the output of `!gcgen`.

Disadvantage: might be slow since it works on all objects.